# How to save a pair of ids with one check_box_tag in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are two sets of ids (id1 and id2) within one row on a form (form_tag), representing a pair of possible combination of id1 and id2 to choose. With `check_box_tag`, one id could be  saved in an array like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'id_array[]', id1 %>
```

The `id_array` is returned as an array in params[:id_array]. Is there a way 2 ids can be saved with one check_box_tag (only need to check once)? We tried:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'id_array[][]', id1, id2 %>
```

and it did not work.

### Update

Here is a single id form implemented:

```
<%= form_tag mass_onboard_user_accesses_path, :method => :put do %>

  <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th><%= t('Engine Name') %></th>
     <th><%= t('Engine Desp') %></th>
  </tr>

<% @engines.each do |r| %>
  <tr>
    <% engine = Engine.find_by_id(r.resource_id)%>
    <td><%= check_box_tag 'id_array[]', r.resource_id %></td>
    <td><%= engine.name %></td>
    <td><%= engine.module_desp %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <%= submit_tag t('Save') ,:name => "save[#{@project_id}]" %>
        </th>
      </tr>


<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire form?

Comment: Could you please write down the resulting array you expect to be posted by your form? I cannot imagine your requirement yet. Is it more like 'id_array = [id1, id2]' or 'id_array[id1] = id2'? From your questions I would guess the first version is what you want, but your approach with 'id_array[][]' suggests the second..

Comment: 2 dimension array would be nice. But really don't care how they are packed within a params as long as it can tell which is which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think to do it is to cheat. I was trying to think how the collection of ids in a single checkbox would map to parameters in the URL and I failed to. So, the cheat is to assume that all params[:id_array] values are potentially an array of strings.

In your view:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'id_arrays[]', [id1, id2].join(",") %>
```

In your controller:

```
ids = []
params[:id_arrays].each do |sub_array|
  ids += sub_array.split(",")
end
```

Or in a less verbose, and arguably less clear, form:

```
ids = params[:id_arrays].to_a.inject([]) {|c, id_array| c + sub_array.split(",") }
```

Except you'd probably encapsulate that in a method:

```
def multiple_id_param(param_name)
  params[param_name].to_a.inject([]) do |c, id_array|
    c + id_array.split(",")
  end
end

ids = multiple_id_param(:id_array)
```

But then I fully appreciate that that's the kind of work you were trying to avoid by just calling the `check_box_tag` with some clever parameters. I guess this answer boils down to: "I don't think you can".

Answer (score 1):

Although your use case is not absolutely clear to me, this might help:

```
<% Outerloop.each do |o| %>
  <% Innerloop.each do |i| %>
    <%= checkbox_tag "id_array[#{o.id}][]", i.id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: '#{ua.id}'=Array(2 element(s))' - only return 1-D array of 2nd id. The first id in #{} was lost. Interesting idea though.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with that command... You can use 'params[:id_array].inspect' to display the array structure that arrives at the server